# Iterated removal of singleton Pythagorean triples

Tags: nt.number-theory, computer-science

Consider the set of all Pythagorean triples (positive integers $a, b, c$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, not necessarily coprime). Then for each integer that appears in exactly one triple, remove that triple from the set and repeat this process an infinite number of times.

For example, 3 is a member of only one triple (3, 4, 5), so that triple is removed. Afterwards, 5 is a member of only one triple (5, 12, 13), so that triple can also be removed, and so on.

Call a triple *stable* if it is never removed by this process, and a positive integer stable if it is a member of at least one stable triple.

For example, 15 is stable because taking each elementwise product of the triples (3, 4, 5) and (5, 12, 13) results in a "magic square" where each row and column is a Pythagorean triple. Since each element in the square is a member of two different triples including only other elements of the square, every row, column, and element of such a square is stable.

$\begin{matrix}
15 & 36 & 39\\
20 & 48 & 52\\
25 & 60 & 65
\end{matrix}$

My questions are

1. Is every stable integer connected to one or more cycles of stable triples as described above? Or are there stable integers which are stable merely because they are the root of an infinitely ascending tree of Pythagorean triples that can't be removed in a countable number of steps?

and

2. Is there a simple algorithm to determine whether an integer is stable?